# Restart a for loop after break

Tags: python, iterator

I have an iterator that consists of several lists of the same size. For my purpose I need to know the length of at least one of these lists. But as it is with iterators they can't be accessed the same way as ordinary arrays. So my idea was to get this length by saying:

```
for i in iter:
    list_len = len(i)
    break
```

And this works, however, when using this list later on, and wanting to loop over it again it skips the first iteration, and basically continues from the next iteration from the previous loop (the one above).

Is there some way to fix this ? Or, what is the pythonic way of doing it ?
I was thinking/reading about doing it like:

```
from itertools import tee

iter_tmp, iter = tee(iter)
for i in iter_tmp:
    list_len = len(i)
    break
```

And yeah, that works too, since I can now use the original `iter` for later use, but it just hurt my eyes that I have to make a loop, import itertools and such just to get the length of a list in an iterator. But maybe that is just the way to go about it ?

UPDATE

Just trying to further explain what I'm doing.

As such iterations is not a list or an array, but in my case, if I were to loop through my iterator I would get something like (in the case of my iterator having four "lists" in it):

```
>>> for i in iter_list:
        print(i)
[1, 2, 5, 3]
[3, 2, 5, 8]
[6, 8, 3, 7]
[1, 4, 6, 1]
```

Now, all "lists" in the iterator has the same length, but since the lists themselves are calculated through many steps, I really don't know the length in any way before it enters the iterator. If I don't use an iterator I run out of memory - so it is a pro/con solution. But yeah, it is the length of just one of the lists I need as a constant I can use throughout the rest of my code.

Comment: If you want the first element of an iterator you can use `next()` instead of `for`+ `break`. You will still consume the first element however.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your iterator? Is there no way to know what length the lists will be beforehand?

Comment: Consider not using `iter` as an identifier (variable name)

Comment: Please add an example for what you are trying to iterate over and what your expected output would be.

Comment: I've added an update to OP

Comment: What do you mean _before it enters the iterator_? Where are your lists from? If you have access to the iterator, could you not report the length from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how iterators work. But you have a few options apart from tee.

You can extract the first element and reuse it when iterating the second time:

```
first_elem = next(my_iter)
list_len = len(first_elem)

for l in itertools.chain([first_elem], my_iter):
    pass
```

Or if you are going to iterate over the iterator more times, you could perhaps listify it (if it's feasible to fit in memory).

```
my_list = list(my_iter)
first_len = len(my_list[0])

for l in my_list:
    pass
```

And certainly not the least, as Palivek said, keep/get the information about the length of the lists (from) somewhere else.

Comment: my vote, but for the 2nd case, you don't need `itertools.chain`, just iterate over the list or `iter(my_list)`

Answer (score 0):

In general iterators are not re-iteratable so you'll probably need to store something additional anyway.

```
class peek_iterator(object):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self._source = iter(source)
        self._first = None
        self._sent = False

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self._first is None:
            self._first = self._source.next()
        if self._sent:
            return self._source.next()
        self._sent = True
        return self._first

    def get_isotropic(self, getter):
        if self._first is None:
            self._first = self._source.next()
        return getter(self._first)

lists = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

i = peek_iterator(lists)

print i.get_isotropic(len) # 3

for j in i: print j        # [1, 2, 3]; [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick and wrap the original iterator in a generator. This way, you can obtain the first element and "re-yield" it with the generator without consuming the entire iterator. The `head()` function below returns the first element and a generator that iterates over the original sequence.

```
def head(seq):
    seq_iter = iter(seq)
    first = next(seq_iter)
    def gen():
        yield first
        yield from seq_iter
    return first, gen()

seq = range(100, 300, 50)
first, seq2 = head(seq)

print('first item: {}'.format(first))

for item in seq2:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
first item: 100
100
100
150
200
250
```

This is conceptually equivalent to [Moberg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822620/4806820), but uses a generator to "re-assemble" the original sequence instead of `itertools.chain()`.